# How Can i Distribute String in rectangle

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to distribute string in rectangle.

[image]

Except each character set position

```
Rectangle  displayRectangle = new Rectangle (new Point(40, 40), new Size (80, 80));

StringFormat format1 = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip);

format1.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center; 

e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, displayRectangle);

e.Graphics.DrawString("Showing Format1", this.Font,

Brushes.Black, (RectangleF)displayRectangle, format1);
```

But, StringFormat Alignment doesn't have distribute alignment. So I want to know a way how to distribute string in rectangle.

Comment: Dude, include some details ? What's going on ?

Comment: using what C# framework?  winforms? wpf? asp.net? directX? console?

Comment: Show us some code please

Comment: not consol, this is winform 
and I Attach code now 
thank you

Comment: You should put some explanation to your code, question, ...!!!

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, I'm going to assume you can/will use the Win32 API (e.g., via. P/Invoke). .NET may have a wrapper for the function I'm going to suggest (but then again, it may not -- I'm really not sure). If it does, it'll be up to you to find and use it. Most of what I'm suggesting is more about the basic approach than the function anyway.

You can use `GetTextExtentExPointI`, which will compute the size of a rectangle necessary to hold a set characters you specify and (importantly) the horizontal position of each character in that rectangle.

So, what you want to do is use this to compute the size of a rectangle and position of each character in that rectangle, with it assuming normal kerning of the characters. Then, you'll divide the width of that rectangle into the width you actually want. This will give you a factor by which each position must increase to get that character to the position you want. You'll then multiply the position it returned for each character by that factor to get your desired position.

Just for example, let's assume it gave you positions of 0, 17, 35 and 44 for the characters with normal spacing. Let's also assume your target rectangle is 1.8 times as wide as the rectangle it computed for normal spacing. You'll take each of those positions and multiply by 1.8 to get the position you want to use for that character, giving 0, 31, 63, and 79 for the "corrected" positions.

Then you'll (obviously enough) go through your string and draw each character at the computed position.

Comment: Thank you for your help
 but that method is win32api
Do not exist anohter way to use .net? and Where Can i get the Example of Full source

Comment: @Kim.J.H: At least to my knowledge, WinForms doesn't support this directly. If you can afford to support only Windows 8, you could use DirectWrite and its support for justification.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it if you just want to literally distribute the characters evenly across the middle of the display rectangle:

[image: Full Justify]

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = "this is distribute";

        Rectangle displayRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(40, 40), new Size(400, 80));
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, displayRectangle);

        int step = displayRectangle.Width / text.Length;
        SizeF szF = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, this.Font); // just to get the HEIGHT

        int y = (displayRectangle.Y + displayRectangle.Height / 2) - (int)szF.Height / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text.Substring(i, 1), this.Font, Brushes.Black, displayRectangle.X + (i * step), y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: but your explained way is that myproject is using way.
I want to konw another way.

Comment: also your code has problem. if length of string over limit, character's whitespace is different.

Comment: The code is a super simple **example**.  You're going to have to consider things like that.  I have no idea how you plan on using this...

Answer (score 0):

Here's my stab at @Jerry Coffin's algorithm using .Net managed methods:
[image: Full Justified Text]

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = "this is distribute";
        Rectangle displayRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(40, 40), new Size(400, 80));
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, displayRectangle);

        StringFormat format1 = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip);
        format1.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        format1.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;

        // SetMeasurableCharacterRanges() can only handle 32 regions max at a time!
        // The below workaround simply measures each character separately:
        RectangleF rcF = (RectangleF)displayRectangle;
        List<Region> regions = new List<System.Drawing.Region>();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            format1.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(new CharacterRange[] {new CharacterRange(i, 1)});    
            regions.AddRange(e.Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(text, this.Font, rcF, format1));
        }

        RectangleF minBounds = regions[0].GetBounds(e.Graphics);
        RectangleF maxBounds = regions[regions.Count - 1].GetBounds(e.Graphics);
        float ratio = (float)displayRectangle.Width / (float)((maxBounds.X + maxBounds.Width) - minBounds.X);

        for(int i = 0; i < regions.Count; i++)
        {
            Region region = regions[i];
            RectangleF boundsF = region.GetBounds(e.Graphics);
            PointF ptF = new PointF(displayRectangle.X + (int)((boundsF.Left - minBounds.X) * ratio), (int)boundsF.Top);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text.Substring(i, 1), this.Font, Brushes.Black, ptF);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your help
but this is not result that i think
because characters space is not equal

Comment: They will be if you use a `fixed width font`.  Otherwise, just divide the width by the number of characters and draw each letter in a simple for loop.